# Why function overwriting is not allowed in ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, scope, es6-modules

Please take a look at the following code;

```js
"use strict"

function test1()
{
    // first
}

function test1()
{
    // second
}

let a=1
console.log( test1 );
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see this code is working, although the second definition of "test1" will overwrite the first one. Now take a look at the following code; **(Html file is different)**

```js
"use strict"

function test1()
{
    // first
}

function test1()
{
    // second
}

let a=1
console.log( test1 );
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="module" src="./test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is not working and gives you this error

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'test1' has already been declared"
```

**( You should run it with a local server to see the error. I cannot produce it here)**

The difference is the scope. In the second example we overwrite the function in module scope which apparently is not allowed although it is allowed in global scope!!! Am I right? Can anybody explain this kind of behaviour for me?

(The same in node.js):

```
> node --experimental-modules --input-type=commonjs --eval 'function a(){}; function a(){}; console.log("ok");'

ok

> node --experimental-modules --input-type=module --eval 'function a(){}; function a(){}; console.log("ok");'
file://[eval1]:1
function a(){}; function a(){}; console.log("ok");
                ^
SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
```

Comment: You posted the same snipped twice

Comment: You confuse overloading with overwriting

Comment: @NullDev: No, the Javascript is the same, but the HTML part loads the Javascript differently.

Comment: FWIW, I don't get an error on Chrome 77, but I am using chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony. I'm not sure if that's a factor or not.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Not getting any error either. Chrome v77.0.3865.90, no additional flags

Comment: @TomFaltesek this is not "overriding" either. Overriding is a term that describes virtual inheritance in object-oriented programming. This is "overwriting", as marzelin has said.

Comment: I corrected the question. Take a look at it again